# Como no cerrar aplicación de servidor con Sockets

Tags: java

tengo una aplicación en java en la que intento levantar un servidor mediante sockets para que después una aplicación cliente le realice peticiones.
El caso es que la aplicación, tal y como la tengo ahora mismo se me cierra, por lo que el cliente nunca podrá conectarse. Adjunto código:

```
public class ServerApplication {

static final int Port = 8000;

int[] asientos[] = {
    {0, 1, 0, 0},
    {1, 1, 1, 0},
    {0, 1, 0, 1},
    {0, 1, 0, 0},
    {1, 1, 1, 0},
    {1, 1, 1, 1},
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0, 1},
    {0, 0, 0, 0}
};

void dibujarAsientos(int[] asientos[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= asientos.length; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (int j = 0; j < asientos[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(asientos[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }
}

public ServerApplication() {
    try {
        ServerSocket skServer = new ServerSocket(Port);
        System.out.println("Escucho al puerto " + Port);
        dibujarAsientos(asientos);
        for (int nClient = 0; nClient < 3; nClient++) {
            Socket sClient = skServer.accept();
            System.out.println("Sirvo al cliente " + nClient);
            OutputStream aux = sClient.getOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream flujo_salida = new DataOutputStream(aux);
            flujo_salida.writeUTF("Hola cliente " + nClient);
            sClient.close();
        }
        System.out.println("Ya se han atendido los 3 clientes");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ServerApplication();
}
```

}

En resumen, quiero que esta aplicación quede siempre ejecutándose en un segundo plano, ya que va a ser el servidor al que el cliente va a realizar peticiones.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

El socket servidor se cierra por esta linea.

```
sClient.close();
```

Si quieres tener un servidor gestionando las peticiones debes de cambiar tu código.
Aqui te dejo un ejemplo de como crear un socket y recibir peticiones.

```
//Servidor
public class MyServerSocket {
    private ServerSocket server;
    public MyServerSocket(String ipAddress) throws Exception {
        if (ipAddress != null && !ipAddress.isEmpty()) 
          this.server = new ServerSocket(0, 1, InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress));
        else 
          this.server = new ServerSocket(0, 1, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
    }
 
    private void listen() throws Exception {
        String data = null;
        Socket client = this.server.accept();
        String clientAddress = client.getInetAddress().getHostAddress();
        System.out.println("\r\nNew connection from " + clientAddress);
        
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));        
        while ( (data = in.readLine()) != null ) {
            System.out.println("\r\nMessage from " + clientAddress + ": " + data);
        }
    }
    
    public InetAddress getSocketAddress() {
        return this.server.getInetAddress();
    }
    
    public int getPort() {
        return this.server.getLocalPort();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyServerSocket app = new MyServerSocket(args[0]);
        System.out.println("\r\nRunning Server: " + 
                "Host=" + app.getSocketAddress().getHostAddress() + 
                " Port=" + app.getPort());
        
        app.listen();
    }
}

//cliente

public class MySocketClient {
    private Socket socket;
    private Scanner scanner;

    private MySocketClient(InetAddress serverAddress, int serverPort) throws Exception {
        this.socket = new Socket(serverAddress, serverPort);
        this.scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
    
    private void start() throws IOException {
        String input;
        while (true) {
            input = scanner.nextLine();
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(this.socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            out.println(input);
            out.flush();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MySocketClient client = new MySocketClient(
                InetAddress.getByName(args[0]), 
                Integer.parseInt(args[1]));
        
        System.out.println("\r\nConnected to Server: " + client.socket.getInetAddress());
        client.start();                
    }
}
```

Antes de ejecutar debes de crear un proyecto java y empaquetarlo en un jar.

Forma de ejecución en consola.

```
    1.- Iniciar el server 
         
         java -cp + jar + clase del servidor +  ip 
         Ejemplo:
         java -cp TCPSocket.jar main.java.MyServerSocket 192.168.100.15
    
    2.- Iniciar el cliente.
    
         java -cp + jar + clase del servidor + ip + puerto
         Ejemplo: 
         java -cp TCPSocket.jar main.java.MySocketClient 192.168.100.15 63015
    
         El puerto lo ves cuando ejecutas el servidor (paso 1)
    3.- Enviar mensaje al server.
        al inicial el cliente te dará un mensaje como el siguiente.
        Connected to Server: /192.168.100.15
        le das enter y escribes el mensaje a enviar.
    4.- En la ventana de consola donde ejecutas el server le das enter y verás el mensaje que se ha enviado.
```

Nota: Este código lo puedes usar, solo cambia el mensaje a enviar y listo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo usé de otra manera pero me sirvió tu ejemplo. Muchas gracias!